# Solr Results boosted according to keyword match

Tags: solr

Does anyone worked on the solr search to boost the result based on maximum search keyword match? Actually I am doing query on Solr to get the result based on multiple keywords search and need to boost the result based on maximum matches keyword.
Let say my search term is field:("suresh" or "ramesh" or "vikas"). Now if any result match all three word then should come first. If any any result match only two word then come 2nd position and so on.
Thanks !

Comment: isnt it not happening with solr? how does solr calculates the score in your case?

Comment: No, It's giving me random. Like first result 2,3 result coming as expected but again 4th result coming unexpected. Like all three matches keyword matches result came in 4th position.

Comment: You'll have to include your actual query, an example of the documents that are matching and how they are ordered and the analysis chain for the field you're querying against. You can append `debug=all` to your query to see how the score is calculated for each document in your result set (i.e. which terms matched and how they contributed to the score).

Comment: I tried below query and it solve by purpose. Thanks 
https://github.com/techiearchive/aem-cheatsheet/blob/master/solr-query/query-sorting.md